# selector in CSS in image and alt

Tags: html, css

```
       <a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" alt="QAAC Portal"/></a>

       <a href="#"><img src="img/2.png" alt=""/></a>

        <a href="#"><img src="img/3.png" alt="SS Conference"/></a>

       <a href="#"><img src="img/4.png" alt="Local Prog Contest"/></a>
```

How can I select all image with alt, but I must not select (alt="").

I want it in one selector like that `img[alt]:not(alt="")`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
img[alt]:not([alt=""]){
  ...insert styles here...
}
```

Try this